Securing Blob Access using Entra ID
I thought this would be simple to find an answer for but I'm struggling and hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I have an Azure Blob Storage account that I'm wanting to put blobs into via code, using a SAS token. However, I want to ensure that only internal employees, from a single user group, can access the blobs themselves. I presume I can secure the container and lock it to the group, but how do I retrieve/generate secure links to send to the users?

As per my understanding, you have set of users in one group they only need to access the blob?

From my understanding, if you want to put blobs via code, any user with access (permission ) to that action can upload blobs. For your condition, I suggest attaching the client credential flow from the Azure app registration and getting the users in that specific group. Then do a cross-validation if the blob uploading user is inside that group and allows his action.

@Venkatesan yes that's correct. I'm not worried about the upload behind the scenes, I know how to do that part, but I'm wanting to send the users secured links, that can't simply be forwarded on (or accessed by unauthorized users).

I would suggest assign Storage Blob Data reader to that storage account with group and now the people in that group will be able to read the files from Storage account. Now if you send only blob link like https://venkat32612.blob.core.windows.net/test/beach.mp4 the people need to access with their user credentials.

ok will test it out, thank you

I tested now - this gives me access to the blob, but only for specific usage scenarios - I can't send a direct, secure link to a user that can't be accidentally forwarded on. I'm wanting something like a OneDrive link, where only an authenticated and authorized user can access the document. Doesn't seem possible with Azure Blobs?

@HiltonGiesenow Check the below possible way to access only the group of users only.  because sas token can be able to access by unauthorized person also.


Securing Blob Access using Entra ID

You can follow the below steps to access the blob from particular group using blob links.
First assign Storage Blob Data Reader role to only read or  Storage Blob Data Contributor role to read and write permission to that group.
After assigning, you can check in the portal:
Portal->storage account-> Access control(IAM)->Role assignments->scope(This resource)

The above condition will be able to read the blob inside the storage account from that group with user.
Now, people in the group login with their credential, Login to az, using az login with user mail and password:

After logging in, you can use the below code to access the links.
Code:
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string blobLink = "https://venkat32612.blob.core.windows.net/test/zxxxe.txt";
        BlobClient blob = new BlobClient(new Uri(blobLink), new DefaultAzureCredential());
        BlobDownloadResult downloadResult = await blob.DownloadContentAsync();
        string downloadedData = downloadResult.Content.ToString(); ;
        Console.WriteLine(downloadedData);
    }
}

Output:
Hello there, Azure Storage. I'm a friendly file ready to be stored in a blob.



Sure, I'm with you there. The problem is you can't share the -direct- path with the user. For instance, I couldn't email them a link to the document directly, like this: https://venkat32612.blob.core.windows.net/test/zxxxe.txt

AFAIK it is not possible.

ok thanks - that seems to be the case from my research also. Thanks for the help with this in any case

@NaveenSharma, the solution did NOT solve the problem, but I upvoted the comment because it at least clarified fully
